# Relatório não é encontrado ao executar .jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports

No netbeans ele encontra o relatório normal, mas quando vou pelo jar, ele não está encontrando.

Já vi alguns tópicos por aqui sobre esse problema, mas mesmo assim não consegui resolver, pois eles falam que é apenas tirar o “src” do caminho da pasta onde está alocado o relatório.

Segue meu código:

```
Connection conn = new SQLConnection().java_db();
if(!jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Selecione...")&&procurar1.getDate()!= null && procurar2.getDate()!=null){
Map p = new HashMap();
p.put("tipoteste", jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
p.put("dataini", procurar1.getDate());
p.put("datafim", procurar2.getDate());
JasperReport relatorio;
JasperPrint impressao;

try {
    relatorio = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new File("").getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Relatorios/reprovadosgeral.jrxml");

    impressao = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, p, conn);
    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(impressao, false);
    view.setTitle("Relatório Reprovados");
    view.setVisible(true);


} catch (Exception e) {

}
}else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preencha todos os campos");
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Dependendo o ambiente onde você tá executando o .jar, pode ser um problema quanto a orientação de pastas, enquanto o Linux utiliza "/", no Windows utiliza "\".

Veja mais em [Viva o Linux](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Diferencas-entre-o-sistema-de-arquivos-do-Windows-e-Linux?pagina=2).

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: As barras estão corretas sim, pois pela IDE ele executa normalmente..

Comment: @GabrielBispo não, não estão. O próprio java tem uma ferramenta para não passar por essa situação. Utilize `File.separator`. O interpretador do jasper não consegue decifrar o SO do computador, por isso que tem que deixar o java verificar isso primeiro.